# hibernate multiple @OneToMany relationships generating more results in parent relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I will start with the result. In the next image I am displaying the result content of company.userAccount. In the database I have only two companies assigned to the same user and 7 services attached to one of the companies.

[image]

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
@Data
@Introspected
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"id"})
public class UserAccount {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userAccount", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Company> companies = new ArrayList<>();

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
@Data
@Introspected
@ToString(exclude = {"userAccount"})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"id", "userAccount"})
public class Company {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_account_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UserAccount userAccount;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "service")
@Data
@Introspected
@ToString(exclude = {"company"})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value= {"id", "company"})
public class Service {
    ...

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Company company;

}


@Transactional
public Service saveService(@Valid @Uuid UUID companyUuid, SaveServiceCommand command) {
    Company company = companyRepository.getCompanyByUuid(companyUuid).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("unrecognized company"));

    Service service = new Service();
    service.setCompany(company);
    service.setName(command.getName());
    service.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());

    return companyRepository.saveCompanyService(service);
}

@Transactional
public Service saveCompanyService(@Valid Service service) {
    entityManager.persist(service);
    return service;
}
```

The generated query (simplified) is

```
select * from user_account a left outer join company c on a.id=c.user_account_id left outer join service s on c.id=s.company_id;
```

This will generate

[image]

Expected result: I was expecting in the UserAccount to see only 2 companies and in one of the companies to have 6 services. Why do I have this result? Why is the same company object multiple times in the list? How can I avoid this?

I believe that one solution would be to change the fetching type of the @OneToMany relationships to LAZY (as they are default) (already tested this solution and it works) but what if I need this type of scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 companies, just like you said. You can notice, that all objects are the same (hashes match). The reason behind this is that the query generates 6 rows for one company and `PersistenceBag` used by hibernate does not remove duplicates by default. Passing `distinct` to your sql would not work, because there is only one parent entity.

But this can be achieved by using hibernate's query hints. Passing `QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH` to your `Query` simply removes duplicated children.

For more information you can refer to [this](https://in.relation.to/2016/08/04/introducing-distinct-pass-through-query-hint/) source.

Comment: How is this applied for the queries generated by relationships definition?

Comment: @tzortzik as said, this is a hibernate standard, you would have to used other mechanism, for example with `EntityManager#createQuery`, where you can pass a hint with `setHint`. Other way would be to manually remove the duplicates, but that is additional logic to maintain.